# If random variables $X$ and $Y$ are "independent for all rational numbers", then can we say that $X$ and $Y$ are independent

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, independence

**Question:-**

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables.
It is given that $P(X\le x, Y\le y)=P(X\le x)P(Y\le y), \forall x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$
Are $X$ and $Y$ independent.

i.e. can we say that $P(X\le x, Y\le y)=P(X\le x)P(Y\le y), \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

**My attempt:-**

Since,

1. for every irrational number $x$, we can always find a sequence of rational numbers $x_n$ that converges to $x$ and
2. Probability is a continuous set function

$\implies P(X\le x_n, Y\le y)=P(X\le x_n)P(Y\le y), \forall y\in\mathbb{Q}$

$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}P(X\le x_n, Y\le y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X\le x_n)P(Y\le y), \forall y\in\mathbb{Q} $

Now, if $x_n$ is an increasing sequence, then $ P(X\le x, Y\le y)=P(X\le x)P(Y\le y), \forall y\in\mathbb{Q}$

( Here, i kind of took the limit inside, because probability is a continuous set function. i.e. $A_i$ is a set of events such that $A_1\subset A_2\subset A_3\dots$ then, $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i)=P(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i)$ )

in a similar way, we can now show that  $ P(X\le x, Y\le y)=P(X\le x)P(Y\le y), \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You have an error in the evaluation of the limit.  You don't want $x_n$ to be an increasing sequence; you want a decreasing sequence (an increasing sequence would give a strict inequality $X < x$ so you could still recover the intended inequality, but it's immediate with a decreasing sequence)

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks for the input. Could you please tell me a book that contains questions like these? I am currently following a first course in probability by sheldon ross, and I have never come across questions like this one in that book.